# Shortcuts trigger events for disabled QActions

Tags: python, qt, qt4

I am using QT4 (4.2.1) with python 2.4 on CentOS.

I assigned QAction with shortcuts to my menu and disable/enable them accordingly.  I have event handlers assigned to the `triggered` event for the actions. Everything works as expected except that the shortcuts trigger the events for disabled actions. For example, I have a Delete QAction with Del shortcut. I see the disabled Delete menu option but if I hit the Del key my `triggered` event handler gets called. This is kind of odd...

Is this by design or I am doing something wrong?

As a workaround I am now checking QAction isEnabled() in each action event handler but is there a way to not get `triggered` events for disabled actions?

Thank you very much for your help,

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaves fine with Qt 4.8.5, and as far as I can tell from the source it should work with versions as old as Qt 4.5.

Try upgrading Qt to a reasonably recent version, or at least try your code on a more modern version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am stuck with the software versions that I have (both QT and python) As long as this is a bug with the older version and I am not doing something wrong, I can live with the workaround that I have.